# How to change the username and computer name?

Tags: username

I clone my No.1 OS in VMware, the username and computer name are node1, now i clone it and want to make the cloned one's username and computer name became node2. how can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

you can change hostname by editing  `/etc/hostname` and user by `usermod -l new_name` you should also change homedir, so it would be easier to create new user? 
moving homedir can be done also with usermod, if necessary :)